# If $P \in \Bbb Z[X]$ and $P(x)=0$, show that $\exists K>0, \forall a/b \in [x-1,x+1], P(a/b) \neq 0$ and $|x- a/b| \ge \frac{K}{|b|^m}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, polynomials

> Let $P \in \Bbb Z[X]$, $m= \text{deg}(P) \ge 1$, $x$ a real root of $P$. Show that
> $$
> \exists K>0, \forall \frac{a}{b} \in [x-1,x+1], P(\frac a b) \neq 0 \implies \vert x- \frac a b \vert \ge \frac{K}{\vert b \vert ^m}.
> $$

What I've done so far:

1. Argue by contradiction: suppose $$
   \forall K>0, \exists \frac{a}{b} \in [x-1,x+1], P(\frac a b) \neq 0 \text{ and }\vert x- \frac a b \vert \le \frac{K}{\vert b \vert ^m}. 
   $$
   Taking $K=\frac 1 {2^n}$, we get two sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ such that
   $$
   \frac{a_n}{b_n} \in [x-1,x+1],\ P(\frac {a_n} {b_n})\neq 0,\ b_n^m (x- \frac{a_n}{b_n}) \to 0
   $$
   and since $\vert b_n \vert \ge 1$ we also have
   $$
   \frac{a_n}{b_n} \to x.
   $$
   So $$
   x - \frac{a_n}{b_n} = o(\frac{1}{b_n^m}) \iff x  = \frac{a_n}{b_n} + o(\frac{1}{b_n^m}).
   $$
   Since $P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^m c_k x^k =0$ we have$$
   P(\frac{a_n}{b_n} + o(\frac{1}{b_n^m}))=_{n \infty} o(\frac{1}{b_n^m})=_{n \infty} 0
   $$
   How can that help?
   I feel that I'm stuck here... Can someone give me a hint to continue in this way or tell me why what I'm doing doesn't work?

Comment: This looks suspiciously close to [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Liouville_numbers_and_transcendence).